# Issue with select lists in jQuery Mobile 1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Example http://jsfiddle.net/A4sqY/3/

this is where I think the issue is:

```
function disableSelectedOption() {
                $('.mySelect > option').each(function () {
                   $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); 
                });
                $('.mySelect > option:selected').each(function () {
                    var disableOption = $(this).val();
                    $('.mySelect > option:not(:selected)').each (function () {
                        if (disableOption === $(this).val()) {
                           $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
                        }                      
                    });
                });    
            }
```

If you change from jQuery Mobile 1.3 to 1.2 they work as expected. Using 1.3 (have to) the select lists are getting screwed up with the disabled and selected attributes. Switching to 1.2 shows how they are suposed to work, when you add another filter, the previous select list value is not selectable in the new one. For whatever reason, when using 1.3 they all display the same selected value and you cannot change it. Using data-role="none" seems to fix this but removes the styling. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `.prop('disabled' true)`?

Comment: Hey Omar, where would I attach that? I replaced the $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); with $(this).prop('disabled', true); to no avail On another note, working through this then back on to the dialog you helped me with

Comment: Honestly I couldn't identify the issue. I tested the fiddle, selected option gets disabled on the rest. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: After you click 'Add another filter', the created select list has the same value 'selected' and when you try and change it you cannot. Change to jQuery Mobile 1.2 to see expected behavior

Comment: Go to this and replace _hello_ with the value you want http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/A4sqY/4/ the problem is the text of the select menu isn't being updated as you're cloning the same select with all its enhancements. I suggest that you append fresh selectmenu and then do modifications rather than cloning it.

Comment: Any idea why this behavior only exhibits with jQ Mobile 1.3? and why adding 'data-role="none"' fixes it? The only drawback is it looses the  'enhancements'.

Comment: Because when you clone it, you call enhancement as well. I don't know why it happens on 1.2 only. So I suggest you append a new select, modify it and then enhance it.

Comment: any hints on how to do that, I want to do it the 'right' way

Comment: The same way yiu do it now, but instead of clone, append new select. Make a `var select = '<select><option>......';` and add it whoever you want. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/v43Qp/